# Force HTTPS in route generation

Tags: ssl, https, asp.net-web-api

How do I force ASP.NET Web.API to generate HTTPS links?

In my MVC app, I am generating urls in the views this way `@Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "People" })`

But if the web app is accessed through HTTP, the links will use the HTTP schema. I want to force the HTTPS for the connections to the Web API.

I know there are examples of the `RequireHttpsAttribute` in internet, but those examples just refuse the connection if HTTPS is required and not provided, what is fine. What I want is that even if the app is accessed through HTTP, the links to the Web API be generated with the HTTPS schema.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`RouteUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492238%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method which allows you so specify the protocol and thus generate an absolute URL with this protocol:

```
@Url.RouteUrl(
    "DefaultApi", 
    new { httproute = "", controller = "People" }, 
    "https"
)
```

Notice the `httproute = ""` route value to indicate that we want to generate a route for a Web API controller and not MVC controller.

Comment: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https: //localhost/MyWebAPI/api/People. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."  -> I didn't think in that :P Thanks.